# Une traduction de « wildcard », appliqué à des personnes ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Je cherche un mot qui exprime une personne :

- qu'on peut utiliser partout
- qui sait « tout » sur « tout »
- ...

Quand je cherches sur Internet, je tombe bien-sûr sur des termes techniques informatiques comme « Joker » mais cela me semble péjoratif pour une personne.

Donc : Quelle serait une bonne traduction de « wildcard » en français **pour une personne** (et mélioratif SVP) ?

**plus d'infos:** je ne cherchait pas une traduction de "Jack of all trades and master of none" (péjoratif) mais un mot *mélioratif*.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *wildcard* utilisé de cette façon en anglais. C'est habituellement utilisé pour décrire quelqu'un sur qui on ne peut pas se fier, qui agit généralement de manière imprévisible.

Comment: "Joker" pour une personne ne me semble pas du tout péjoratif en français. On y fait référence à la carte à jouer qui peut remplacer toutes les autres, et pas à sa signification anglaise (blagueur). http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/joker/44962?q=joker#44913

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec @Kareen. La definition donnée par l'OP correspond plutôt à "Jack of all trades"

Comment: @StephaneGimenez: merci beaucoup pour avoir changé le titre!  +1 moral!  ;-)

Comment: @radouxju: +1 aussi.  Dommage que ce n'est pas une réponse, mais qu'un commentaire.  **;-)**

Comment: For a couple of English suggestions similar to *wild card* from card game terminology, there’s “[He’s our] **trump card**” or “[She’s our] **ace in the hole**,” from which you could get to “[C’est notre] **atout** majeur/clé/en reserve,” and “[C’est notre] **carte maîtresse**.”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suivant l'usage précis que l'on veut en faire, beaucoup de mots peuvent convenir, souvent de manière figurative :

- Un `passe-partout`. Se réfère à une "master key", une clé qui ouvre différentes serrures.
- Un `touche-à-tout`, qui me semble être la meilleur traduction de "Jack of all trades" (mais dont le sens induit est l'absence de spécialisation => "master of none").
- `Débrouillard`.
- `Joker` qui n'est pas péjoratif. Généralement disposer d'un joker dans un jeu est plutôt bon. C'est aussi un mot employé régulièrement pour traduire "wildcard", dans le cas par exemple du caractère "*" lors d'une requête dans une base de données.
- On peut aussi qualifier la personne comme étant `polyvalente`.
- La réponse de Graffito : `Couteau suisse`.
- `L'homme de toutes les situations` , bien qu'un peu long, me semble également approprié.

Comment: Très bon choix selon moi :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Assuming that "wildcard" refers to a person or a thing that could solve a situation.

For a thing, you may use the expression "couteau suisse" (*Swiss army knife*; *multi-purpose tool*) in its figurative sense.

For a person, you may use "homme providentiel" (*the right man for the job, by some happy coincidence*).